# next-auth with keycloak, how to kick user out of app when there is inactivity

Tags: typescript, session, next.js, next-auth

I followed this tutorial and build a simple website around it.

https://medium.com/inspiredbrilliance/implementing-authentication-in-next-js-v13-application-with-keycloak-part-1-f4817c53c7ef
https://medium.com/inspiredbrilliance/implementing-authentication-in-next-js-v13-application-with-keycloak-part-2-6f68406bb3b5

I still use most of the code and at the bottom of the tutorial is a link to the github repository if anyone needs it to answer my question.

I want my user to be kicked out of the app (so he is not logged in and there is no session), when he is inactive for 5minutes and the site gets reloaded. So when he is on a privat site (nextjs middleware matcher) he needs to login again.

What I tried was to use this in my SessionGuard:

https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/discussions/6401

I used the code by the user kn327 and changed signOut() to federatedLogout().

I set the timeoutMs to 15000 (so 15 seconds) and after 15 seconds of inactivity, instead of a logout I got an alert on my website that there is no session.

Actually kinda confused, because I also tryed signOut() and it didn't worked for me.

Thanks in advance!